# WPF execute a function before a particular event occurs?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Is there a way to execute a piece of code before an event occurs?

example when we say Expanded="OnExpand" 
here the code inside OnExpand occurs after the Expanded event occurs. What if I want to execute a piece of code before that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're talking about the Expander control, you could subclass it and override the IsExpanded property, raising your own PreviewExpanded event before calling `base.IsExpanded = value;`

Comment: And is there a better way to do it globally? I dont want to change all the Expander controls application wide to MyExpander

Comment: There might be a way to take advantage of the fact that IsExpanded is a DependencyProperty, but right now I'm not sure how.

Comment: also I'm a newbie to .net and wpf. Any pointer to creating a custom control and adding events to that class, will be great help

Comment: Sure, there's a bunch of [tutorials](http://www.wpftutorial.net/HowToCreateACustomControl.html) out there, but I recommend the O'Reilly book '[Programming WPF](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596510374)' by Chris Sells and Ian Griffiths for the best guide out there.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Preview Events

A possible work around for the expander not having a PreviewExpanded event is to  handle the PreviewMouseDown event and do a hit test to see if its on the Toggle Button.

Alternatively it may be possible to extend the Expander Class something along the lines of
I did not test this at all no idea is it really works

```
public class MyExpander: Expander
{
    public event EventHandler<EventArgs> PreviewExpanded;

    public void OnPreviewExpanded()
    {
       PreviewExpanded(this,new EventArgs());
    }

    public override void OnExpanded()
    {
       PreviewExpanded()
       base.OnExpanded();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If whatever object you are working with supports this behavior it will be in a matching "Preview" event. So, these two events are a before and after matched set.
KeyDown()
PreviewKeyDown()

Expander does not have a preview event for Expanded, if that is what you are working with.